# How do I launch a windows SQL server instance into GCP using Terraform?

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

All of the Terraform GCP tutorials I've seen teach you how to launch a debian instance into GCP:

```
image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
```

The way I'm defining the new GCP instance right now is like this but I want to find a way to do the same thing using windows sql server:

```
// A single Compute Engine instance
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone

  tags = [var.instance_name, var.env_name]
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }

  }
```

So what if I want to launch another OS? I want to launch windows server 2019 with MS SQL. What about the latest ubuntu or red hat? Basically I'd like to know how to launch other OSes into GCP using Terraform but I am most interested in the latest MS SQL right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using image data so your SQL instance will be like

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "sqlserver" {
  name         = var.instance_name
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone

tags = [var.instance_name, var.env_name]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = data.google_compute_image.sqlserverimage.self_link
      size = 100
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = var.vpc_selflink
  }
  
}

data "google_compute_image" "sqlserverimage" {
  family = "sql-std-2019-win-2019" 
  project = "windows-sql-cloud"
  
}
```